# Combining UIImageViews yields empty image with 0 bytes

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to merge two `UIImageView`s together into `combinedView`. The issue I am encountering is that after I have added the `self.firstImageView` and `self.secondImageView` as subviews to my `combinedView`, the output I get when I check the byte size of `combinedView.image` is 0.  I need `combinedView.image` to be eventually passed to my backend in a JEPGRepresentation, so am unsure how else I could approach to combining the views together, or what I am doing incorrectly at the moment.

Thanks for your help!

```
UIImageView *combinedView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[combinedView addSubview:self.firstImageView];
[combinedView sendSubviewToBack:self.firstImageView];
[combinedView addSubview:self.secondImageView];
[combinedView bringSubviewToFront:self.secondImageView];

NSData *firstPicData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.firstImageView.image, 1.0);
NSLog(@"Size of first:%d",[firstPicData length]); //outputs a non-zero number

NSData *secondPicData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.secondImageView.image, 1.0);
NSLog(@"Size of second:%d",[secondPicData length]); //also outputs a non-zero number

NSData *combinedPicData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(combinedView.image, 1.0);
NSLog(@"Size of combined:%d",[combinedPicData length]); //! outputs 0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding self.firstImageView and self.secondImageView as a sub view of combined view and more over you didn't assign any image to combinedView. So [combinedPicData length] will be only 0 always.

Refer the following links for merging of two images.

[iOS - Merging two images of different size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208951/ios-merging-two-images-of-different-size)

[blend two uiimages based on alpha/transparency of top image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309757/blend-two-uiimages)

[Merge Two Image on to one Image programmatically in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273271/merge-two-image-on-to-one-image-programmatically-in-iphone)

[How to merge two half images in ios app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193893/how-to-merge-two-half-images-in-ios-app)

Comment: Thanks, the first link was especially helpful.